# jquery toggle event to change image src

Tags: jquery, toggle

I've got a problem with the toggle event. As you can see with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roddr8mu/1/), I'm trying to create the yosemite menu bar with jquery.

I'm using :

```
$('.apple-button').click(function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

I want the apple logo to return black when I click again on it. It only returns black when I click somewhere else. I know that I should have used the background property of my button to insert the image but I'm sure we can do it like this.

I tried to create a boolean to know if the button is active or not, but it doesn't work..

Any help ? Thanks

Comment: I updated my fiddle. Please take a look at it. I had to add the conditional code to the `html` click event. You can find the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/roddr8mu/3/)

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure this is necessary to duplicate the conditional code in the html click event. Juste need to set the variable black to true. Please have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/roddr8mu/5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add some conditional code in there... I added:

```
if(black === true){
    $('.apple-img').attr('src', 'http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/396482apple.png');
    black = false;
} else {
    $('.apple-img').attr('src', 'http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/233770appleblack.png');
    black = true;
}
```

After making the global variable `black` and setting it to `true`:

```
var black = true;
```

[**Updated Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/roddr8mu/3/)

Comment: Actually, a little somthing was missing... Here is the solution http://jsfiddle.net/roddr8mu/5. Thanks King Shimkus